# Framer motion animations flashing when used in conjunction with custom css

Tags: css, accessibility, framer-motion

Here's the sandbox for this question - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nervous-leaf-wblzxc

When I use Framer motion animations with custom css

```scss
// https://prismic.io/blog/nextjs-accessibility#:~:text=nowrap%3B%0A%7D-,Reduced%20motion,-Due%20to%20a
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {

  // https://css-tricks.com/revisiting-prefers-reduced-motion/
  * {
    animation-duration: 0.001ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important; // Hat tip Nick/cssremedy (https://css-tricks.com/revisiting-prefers-reduced-motion-the-reduced-motion-media-query/#comment-1700170)
    transition-duration: 0.001ms !important; // SPECIFICALLY THIS LINE
  }
}
```

and I have reduced motion enabled, the framer motion animations "flash". **Chrome and Edge don't flash whereas Firefox and Safari does.**

To see the "flash"

1. enable reduced motion
2. Go to the sandbox in Firefox (and maybe Safari, haven't tested there)
3. Hover over the second box

Comment: *"1. enable reduced motion"*.  How? It'd be better if you have directions on how to do that rather than each person reading the question and having to look that up.  Also, I don't see a question. Are you asking if others see the flash? Are you asking how to eliminate the flash?

Comment: *"3. Hover over the **second line**"*.  The second line of text in the example? So the line that says "If the custom css is NOT commented out..."? When I hovered over it, nothing happened. I can see a short white horizontal line a ways down that when I hover over it, it changes to a short vertical line. Is that the animation you're talking about? With animations on, it smoothly glides between the two. With animations off, it jumps directly between the two, with no intermediate transition, but it doesn't flash for me on firefox (pc). You mentioned safari. Are you using firefox on a mac?

Comment: Go to settings or devtools to turn on reduced motion. Different based on the OS you're using. There are two horizontal lines on that page that each have an animation. Hover over the second of the two and at the end of its animation it flashes on firefox (make sure you hover till the end of the animation).

Comment: Also have updated to be boxes instead of lines.

Comment: Just tried it on firefox/pc. The box glides between the two states when animation is on and just swaps between the two states when animation is off. No flashing is happening for me.

Comment: Are you on mac?